# Java To C# Via Soap Web Service Passing Wrong Date Value

Tags: java, c#, web-services, soap

I have a web service written in C# deployed on a windows server. One of the services(Generate Letter) accepts a C# "DateTime" request parameter.

The client is written in Java and when it calls the Generate Letter service it passes a "java.util.Calendar" object. For some reason some specific dates when passed from Java to the C# web service gets changed through transport. For example I pass a Java date of 1/3/1945 (March 1st 1945), but when I receive it on the C# web service end it is changed to 2/28/1945(Feb 28th 1945).

I have debugged on the Java client side all the way till the soap envelope is packaged and indeed it's sending the date 1/3/1945, but on the C# side as soon as it is received it is changed to 2/28/1945. This problem does not happen for every date. Only for a few specific dates.

Does anybody have any idea if the soap is doing anything behind the scenes? Is something happening during the transport layer that is not visible to me? Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: This almost sounds like a UTC shift.  Meaning 12:01AM GMT on March 1st 1945 is still 02/28 in other parts of the world.  Are you sending a time component with your date?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem and it's on the Java Client side. For some reason the Java Calendar object date depending on the Year changes the timezone either from EDT to EST. For Example, when I use the year 1945 the Java Calendar object uses the timezone of EDT which causes the time to be pushed back by 1 hour on the C# side. But when I use the year 2017, the Java Calendar Object date uses EST timezone which causes no problem on the C# webservice. Is there a reason why depending on the year the timezone changes from EDT to EST?